# Adobe page sizes

Tags: registry, pdf-generation

Does anyone know the registry key to write (and/or code) for changing Adobe PDF paper sizes? I do know that they are coded as numbers, eg letter = 7, legal = 8 etc. This doesn't seem to appear anywhere on the internet

Answer (score 1):

bprintSetPageSize

Select **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\** in regedit then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find bprintSetPageSize